# What's the difference between `v1.2.3` and `qv(1.2.3)` under `use version`?

Tags: perl, version

Trying to compare version numbers with more than one dot, I wonder how to do it:

Perl has a `version` module that seems to do that job, but I wonder:

```perl-db
  DB<1> use version

  DB<2>  x '1.2.3' > '1.2.29'
0  ''
  DB<3>  x '1.2.3' >= '1.2.29'
0  1
  DB<4>  x '1.2.3' cmp '1.2.29'
0  1
  DB<5>  x '1.2.3' cmp '1.2.29'
0  1
  DB<6> x qv(1.2.3)
0  v1.2.3
  DB<7> x qv(1.2.3) > qv(1.2.29)
0  ''
  DB<8> x qv(1.2.3) < qv(1.2.29)
0  1
  DB<9> x '1.2.3' == '1.2.29'
0  1
  DB<10> x v1.2.3
0  "\cA\cB\cC"
  DB<11> print v1.2.3

  DB<12> print qv(1.2.3)
v1.2.3
```

So `qv(1.2.3)` is converted to `v1.2.3`, but when I print `v1.2.3` that is converted to three binary bytes ("\cA\cB\cC").
Why doesn't `x qv(1.2.3)` print the binary string, and how would I compare version strings like `3.17.34` correctly?

Perl being used is 5.18.2 (in case it makes a difference).

## Add-On

When I tried it while debugging a real program, I got different output:

```perl-db
  DB<2> x qv(1.2.3)
0  version=HASH(0x2faee10)
   'original' => 'v1.2.3'
   'qv' => 1
   'version' => ARRAY(0x2faf3f8)
      0  1
      1  2
      2  3
  DB<3> print qv(1.2.3)
v1.2.3
```

Now I'm completely confused.

Comment: The documentation says `qv` is deprecated and shouldn't be used, btw (At least for modern versions of perl; don't know when it was listed as such and 5.18 is pretty old)

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/version)?

Comment: I think part of it is you're seeing differences between literal version strings and version *object* stringification but don't have time to sit down and play with it right now.

Comment: `'1.2.3' > '1.2.29'`, `'1.2.3' > '1.2.29'` and `'1.2.3' == '1.2.29'` would have warned if you had warnings on.

Comment: On `qv`:  Amazingly it's used in the SYNOPSIS for my version, but under EXPORTED FUNCTIONS there's a statement that it's "no longer recommended". Still it's exported by default. Finally it's much more handy than `version->declare`.

Comment: @ikegami No, perl 5.18.2 *does not* warn you.

Comment: @U. Windl, Yes it does. `Argument "1.2.29" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at -e line 1.` and `Argument "1.2.3" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at -e line 1.` This warning was present in 5.8.8 and surely far earlier.

Comment: I still have `qv` in some places. As long it works for the version you provide it, there's no issue. IIRC, the issue was with how it handles versions with only two parts??? That would make a good question if only to document the problem. But I have no time for that this week.

Answer (score 6):

> What's the difference between `v1.2.3` and `qv(1.2.3)` under `use version`?

[`v1.2.3`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Version-Strings) creates the same string as `chr(1).chr(2).chr(3)`.<sup>[1]</sup> It has nothing to do with the version module.

`qv` creates an object of class "version".

---

> how would I compare version strings like 3.17.34 correctly?

To compare version strings, first create version objects. `qv` is deprecated, and `version->declare` should be used instead.

```perl
version->declare( "v1.2.3" )
version->declare( "1.2.3" )
version->declare( v1.2.3 )
```

Then use numerical comparison operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `<=>`) to compare them.

```perl
version->declare( '1.2.3' ) > version->declare( '1.2.29' )
```

---

1. Almost. The scalar created by v literal has magic attached to it, identifying it to be such a scalar.

Comment: Can you give a reference where the `v` is described? It's neither in "perlsyn", nor in "perlop"!

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Version-Strings